# Adding Grails to an exsisting project

Tags: java, tomcat, grails

I have an existing system built in Java we currently expand that by adding JSPs and Classes but we are given a deployed project. I would like to consider adding new features with Grails but I'm wondering how I can get both parts into the same context path in Tomcat. Is there any way to make this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grails classes compile to .class files just as java classes do. It is only a matter of packaging to deploy a mix of the two in the same .war. In theory (the way I understand it), there's no reason for it not to be possible. I would take apart a simple grails app .war and see if it requires anything special (*.xml) to run: if not, that you just have to package java and groovy binary files in a single .war.

Would like to hear how it went, though. :)

Comment: I actually had tried that method but I could never seem to make the context xml files to work together. I still think at it's heart mixing the two into one war is the only way to make it work. When I tried to deploy a grails war in a subcontex it falls apart.